# c# creating dynamic textbox in a second form

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I am trying to write a code in order to create dynamic textboxes.

I have Function class and have a second form in my program named `ProductForm.cs`

What I wanna do is to read some data with a function named `GetSpecs` in my `Function.cs` and than inside `GetSpecs` I want to call a function in another class and send data to my other function under `ProductForm.cs` class.

I am getting  blank form at the end.

a part of my `GetSpecs` function:

```
private String GetSpecs(String webData)
{
   ......
   ProductForm form2 = new ProductForm();
   form2.CreateTextBox(n);
}
```

ProductForm.cs

```
public void CreateTextBox(int i)
    {
        ProductForm form2 = new ProductForm();
        form2.Visible = true;
        form2.Activate();

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 20;

        for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
            {
                String name = "txtBox_" + row.ToString();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Name = name;

                tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
                tb.Height = height;
                tb.Width = width + row * 2;
                x += 25 + row * 2;
                this.Controls.Add(tb);

            }
            y += 25;

        }

    }
```

I get a blank form of ProductForm. Textboxes are not created or I cannot see them.

If I put textbox inside

```
private void ProductForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I can see textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the controls to the current form: `this.Controls.Add(tb);`, you need to add them to the other form:

```
form2.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating showing a brand new `ProductForm` instance (in the `form2` variable), then adding controls to `this` (which is never shown).

Comment: +1 - you need the other instance of the form.  BTW, it's not good design to have UI components poke at other UI components.  It creates coupling.  @Val: read up on MVC.

Comment: Many thanks for all of you. You explained it quite well. It is my bad not to see this error. You are all super heroes of mine guys.